What material/approach is best to stop a thin "release" cable rubbing around a metal corner?
The handbrake release cable on my Ford S-Max TITANIUM Duratorq '08 has snapped. I have a replacement, but the reason it failed is that it was rubbing on the corner of the handle's frame. It looks like the cable was in the right place, but the consistent rubbing of metal on metal for a few years has caused the failure.

So I'm thinking of putting something there on the corner to stop - or at least delay - another failure. Obviously, the "ideal" approach would be frictionless, like the wheel that is present on the other tight turn of the cable at the bottom of the handle, but it's not at all feasible on this corner - it needs to be a thin material.
So what I want to know is what is the best approach here? - What can I put there at the corner between the frame and the cable and grease up to reduce friction and delay another failure for as long as possible?
